# Linking to wordpress posts for a particular location using a tag "name" attribute

Tags: php, wordpress

I am linking a wordpress post by using the below code.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( 15 ); ?>"
```

Which renders as below

http://mydomainname.com/?p=15

But when the users click, it should open up on a specific location, so I have used `a` tag with the attribute name to show that area directly.

Below is my HTML code.

```
<a name="fi"></a>
```

So the rendered URL would be like the below.

http://mydomainname.com/?p=15#fi

When I manually type like the below, it opens up perfectly on the location that I want it to open, but I do not know how to make changes to `<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( 15 ); ?>"` to achieve what I am looking for.

Comment: `<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( 15 ); ?>#fi">` should do it?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `#fi` after the php code will achieve this:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( 15 ); ?>#fi">Some link</a>
```

that will print out to `http://mydomainname.com/?p=15#fi`